# Beginner Ruby if else

Tags: ruby, if-statement

I've check to see if the program is recieving number and names and it is. I'm wondering why doesn't it print "fred" when input number is 1?

```
number = ARGF.read.chomp
names = %w{fred betty barney}
if number == 1
  puts names[0]
elsif number == 2
  puts names[1]
elsif number == 3
  puts name[2]
end
```

Comment: looks like number is a string, shouldn't the comparisons be like "1", "2" and "3" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`number` is a string, not an integer. You can either convert to an integer:

```
number = ARGF.read.chomp.to_i
```

or you can test against strings instead:

```
if number == "1"
  ...
  ...
  ...
```

Comment: Gosh, that is killing me on almost every program I write...convert to string and integer. Regardless, thanks a lot for you response, much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

`number` is likely a string here, but you are comparing it with an integer.

```
1 == '1' # false
```

try

```
number = ARGF.read.chomp.to_i # note the to_i here
names = %w{fred betty barney}
if number == 1
  puts names[0]
elsif number == 2
  puts names[1]
elsif number == 3
  puts names[2]
end
```

---

Also, you can use a `case/when` statement when you want to take a different path based on multiple values of a single variable.  This is usually the cleaner way to handle this type of flow.

```
number = ARGF.read.chomp.to_i
names = %w{fred betty barney}

case number
when 1
  puts names[0]
when 2
  puts names[1]
when 3
  puts names[2]
end
```

---

Or in this case, the even more simple:

```
number = ARGF.read.chomp.to_i
names = %w{fred betty barney}
puts names[number-1]
```

should work.

Comment: Using a `case` statement is better for a number of reasons: It's significantly faster to execute, it is easier to read especially when mapping several values to a singular action as no `or` is required, and it's impossible to inadvertently assign with `=` instead of comparing with `==`. You're also, worryingly, the only answer that recognized this is an array indexing problem and doesn't need that kind of logic at all.

Comment: "It's significantly faster to execute" ... [citation needed]

Comment: Not a citation, but related at least: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178240/which-is-faster-in-ruby-a-hash-lookup-or-a-function-with-a-case-statement

Answer (score 3):

I know you're learning `if...else`, but keep in mind you can also do this:

```
number = ARGF.read.chomp.to_i - 1
names = %w{fred betty barney}

puts names[number]
```

Answer (score 2):

The `number` is a string.  You can check that that by printing its class like this:

```
p number.class
```

You need to convert `number` to an integer like this:

```
number = ARGF.read.chomp.to_i
```

Keep in mind though that `to_i` would return `0` for invalid string.  Do it only when you are sure about the incoming data.

Try this on [Codepad](http://codepad.org/iwzwxZra).